# How to making volume stay the same across reboots?

Tags: sound, volume-control

I use headphones with my computer, and when I reboot, the volume gets set to 100%.

Hence, when the logon screen comes up, the drum sound plays through my headphones at maximum volume, which is... well I think you know where I'm going with this...

**So, how can I make the volume stay the same across reboots?**

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Huh. I run 14.04 and it remembers my volume setting automatically.

Comment: Well, it's possible with a couple scripts but as wjadrea said, the volumes by default should remain the same. There's probably an issue with your alsa or pulseaudio daemon

Comment: @Serg - Are they any commands I can run to help debug?